# Magento 2: Too many redirects behind traefik reverse-proxy

Tags: apache, docker, reverse-proxy, magento2, traefik

In front of my web servers and Docker applications I'm running Traefik to handle load balancing and reverse-proxy. In this specific case Magento 2 is running on another host in the same private network as the Traefik host.

1. Traefik: 192.168.1.30
2. Magento: 192.168.1.224

Traffic is coming into the firewall on port 80/443 and forwarded to Traefik which forwards the request based on the domain name (in this case exampleshop.com).

My Traefik configuration looks like this:

```
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[backends]
  [backends.backend-exampleshop]
    [backends.backend-exampleshop.servers.server1]
    url = "http://192.168.1.224:80
    passHostHeader = true
[frontends]
  [frontends.exampleshop]
  backend = "backend-exampleshop"
    [frontends.exampleshop.routes.hostname]
    rule = "Host:exampleshop.com"
```

For regular websites above configuration always worked as expected (a working HTTPS connection with valid Let's Encrypt cert) but in this Magento 2 case it results in:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Therefore I'm unable to reach both my homepage as well as my admin page. Looking at the Database records I've configured both my unsecure as secure URL as https://exampleshop.com to avoid redirect errors.

Apache is listening fine on port 80, and when contacted directly (by changing my hosts file) the page gets displayed just fine over HTTP.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Command out below code solved this case **OR**
- Enable ACME on your Traefik and switch SSL mode on Cloudflare to `Full` (if enabled)

```sh
[entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that 192.168.1.224 is the IP (local) where Traefik is installed.

`entryPoints.http` : `address = ":80"` == `address = "0.0.0.0:80"`

- https//exampleshop.com

  - `entryPoints.https` (because https == port 443)
  - `frontends.example1` (because `rule = "Host:exampleshop.com"`)
  - `backend-example1`: `server = "http://192.168.1.224:80"`
  - `entryPoints.http` because `:80` == http://192.168.1.224:80
  - redirection to `entryPoints.https`
  - etc

Try to change the port of your local application.

Comment: 192.168.1.30 would be the IP where Traefik is installed. 192.168.1.224 is the IP where Apache/Magento is listening on. I'm not really clear on what you're saying. I have the entrypoints (see updated question) already defined as you describe, but it results in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the config was completely valid but Cloudflare's crypto/SSL settings were set to Flexible instead of Full; causing a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this as well, but I've found I have to add this:

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-proxy-headers: "X-Forwarded-Proto: https"
```

In our kubernetes ingress manifests and it fixes it.